# c# winForms how to filter combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have combobox which dropDownStyle is dropDown, datasource is arraylist . 
When user input value in combo box i want to filter and show in list only that value which is look like inputed string.

please help

Comment: yes..........................

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the following properties on ComboBox to get the autocomplete feature

```
comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
```